# Show Contour on less dense data in vega?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have build a contour plot,
Data is slightly less dense, which is

[image]

I can't see the contour boundary lines, Also I grouped data based on 3rd column "outlier" which has 1 and 0 values, I can calculate the threshold value for the boundary from python, but I am not sure sure how to use that here

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.json",
    "title": {
    "text": "Outlier Distribution between Duration Vs Age",
    "anchor": "middle",
    "fontSize": 16,
    "frame": "group",
    "offset": 4
  },
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "boundary", "value": 0.0,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -1, "max": 1, "step": 0.1}
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source",
      "url" : {
          "index": "model_data",
          "body": {
            "size":10000,
            "_source": ["duration", "credit_amount", "asnm", "age", "outlier"]           
          }
        }  
        "format": {"property": "hits.hits"},
    },
    {
      "name": "density",
      "source": "source",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "kde2d",
          "groupby": ["_source.outlier"],
          "size": [{"signal": "width"}, {"signal": "height"}],
          "x": {"expr": "scale('x', datum.duration)"},
          "y": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.age)"},
          "bandwidth": {"signal": "[boundary, boundary]"}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "contours",
      "source": "density",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "isocontour",
          "field": "grid",
          "levels": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "linear",
      "round": true,
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "source", "field": "_source.duration"},
      "range": "width"
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "round": true,
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "source", "field": "_source.age"},
      "range": "height"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {
        "data": "source", "field": "_source.outlier",
        "sort": {"order": "descending"}
      },
      "range": "category"
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "grid": true,
      "domain": false,
      "orient": "bottom",
      "tickCount": 5,
      "title": "Duration"
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "grid": true,
      "domain": false,
      "orient": "left",
      "titlePadding": 5,
      "title": "Age"
    }
  ],

  "legends": [
    {"stroke": "color", "symbolType": "stroke"}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "marks",
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "source"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "_source.outlier"},
          "size": {"value": 150}
        }, 
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "_source.duration"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "_source.age"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "from": {"data": "density"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"value": 0},
          "y": {"value": 0},
          "width": {"signal": "width"},
          "height": {"signal": "height"},
          "aspect": {"value": false}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "heatmap",
          "field": "datum.grid",
          "color": {"expr": "scale('color', datum.datum.outlier)"}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "clip": true,
      "from": {"data": "contours"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1},
          "strokeOpacity": {"value": 1},
          "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "outlier"}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        { "type": "geopath", "field": "datum.contour" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Plot comes out like
[image]

Is it possible to show the contours for less dense data

and

I can make the data points in different colours based on grouping, but I need values inside boundary in one colour, and outside boundary in another colour.

the python version of this plot looks like below, which I am recreating in Vega, I am expecting some what similar that way

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Vega *Contour* should work with any size dataset.

To set contours to specific colors, specify a scale to use in *heatmap.*

Here is an example based on this dataset:

https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/2994

```
 "scales": [

{
  "name": "scale_contour_color",
          "domain": {"data": "contours", "field": "contour_id"},
          "range": ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"]
},


...


 "marks": [

 {
      "name": "countour_path",
      "type": "path",
      "clip": true,
      "from": {"data": "contours"},
       "transform": [{"type": "geopath", "field": "datum.contour"}],
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 3},
          "fill": {"scale": "scale_contour_color", "field": "contour_id"},
          "opacity": {"value": 0.7},
          "stroke": {"value": "transparent"}
        }
      }
     
    },
...
```

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXAVgAyoDQjgUwgczhiTUxAAcBDKKCAO3xKykpkqQG1Q7KBbHJCADOAewCuAJwDGArADdKAGzE4hnUAA8kARiwBPHVgBeO1AF8MmpACZ9hkCcTbzlkFsQBmO0+OmLVxAAWb10HP1d3ZBDfJxcAgDZosNj-N3sDRFtk51T3LIysxzRcpC8QApiciKRg8ptKuLSUb0LwhJaGkp86z07qzO8yxyqAsoyhtqba8b6AqJ6JlP7Ehdmm0Iza4ca87y3J9zGatfdp4+ydph79pfbrk-Sr7a78p4PS73nn-rPmi675hkvkgALTaeKXRArIEPboZFbfAKvKGwo4o-4-bwI95-eGw6FIbEpAC6qR4-EEUBwdCEEBgBiwokkMkETOkshAMAklBpADMRBJeOpOXpyAJECAANZU6xQECMiBGcVcYQEHiKQSQWAIVK0-DqwS4AhEEBmYlYdygHAacgSVlSJQ4AAUAHINC6MAACFgwMS8AB0GgAlKbvFabXaJUIHYpnS69B7vaw-f69CGLOA8IRiBKTFgpOI6DA1IguSozWS+OKQAWi+IJGpGfWWRKqTS6QzOdy+QKhYgVfSxYIIKJazB6-KQLyIDhFHKJfgJNBJ7G5LOSwB2VKD6vQakwCDTnB2rCUEs1kR1yQAfWXFfNwhjqmF5Or0cd17H9c-IkUAsnUAiLwlD0EgoA+uwEpfpIjZTjOc6CNBEi3nKGbdvgyogBIOBylgAo8hhk56LOf5gJOi44NSk4AEbKBy9C0PgIiTnIEC-jgxCkq4r6CFoWA7oIij0DglAnlhhbzmWOBYHQEAtlJxjHsxiC8koQjSSAgHAaBiDgawkHCM2HJHghEpaGhBHVlq8ChtwVaCJ2AkSkJdAiWJEgSUgCkgLJ8kSCoikeUgqmKOpzBASBdBgZp+mskZk4mfOdQWQw1ZGtmpoPpQGjPv2oDvrGvHkUukn+RpWmRcFakaQKM5FoI1EiDA45CrqT4OcVy6lmV4XaVFKnVXhS77oJOC8sQZpYMBEiSiWKo8VBhbjjeVA2fxorVqtCD5kJ5BeT1U4eX2elsIhl7LQ2oZdjyQj8oKwpOSAGEiFtCXwUlPopkhmVYNSBZUtFYjkD64r5VyIiSjgADq0A2bpIAKHRpQZtOigavDBVvk+P5XshBZ-mJiVnbjKFXS9lBSB20WIyoSCoP6W6MuDkPU0otMSlyN1UNh9VmHzlYUhK02zZOj1CHovCNRqWC8kd0UQXFzICBmf0iAD8NAyD0WWo+jpFTL71FRmGT5e1EqdkT5tXbSSqs0jQQoxAaN2+zIAAMRSJ7pr86SQA)

[image]

If you want more specific help on your Vega spec, please post a working example with data at the Vega online editor.